# Using Local Special Variables

Tags: global-variables, common-lisp

For prototyping convenience I've relied on a number of global variables which are heavily used throughout the code. But now I'd like to make some of them local (but dynamic). Is there any significant downside (eg, efficiency, something else) to declaring them locally `special` instead of global?

Comment: I wouldn't expect an efficiency issue. All the unpopular features of `special` variables apply, obviously.

Comment: Can you summarize the unpopular features so I could review them?

Comment: So the question is about local variables declared locally as special?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unpopular features of special variables include:

- Lack of referential transparency

This makes it harder to reason functionally about your code. It means that your function produces different results with syntactically equivalent calls.

- Introduce bugs

If a lexical variable is defined somewhere in your code (eg. in a system function), you will overwrite it and cause bugs.

- Confusing

Special (dynamic) binding is unpopular, and will confuse your readers who are not familiar with it.

- Unnecessary

Just use lexical binding, or even anaphoric macros instead.

More information:

Anaphoric macros See Let Over Lambda by Doug Hoyte, or Paul Graham's anaphoric macros.

LiSP (Lisp in Small Pieces) has a section on binding and dynamic binding

Elisp has dynamic binding by default, and enforced dynamic binding for a long time

Many early lisps had dynamic binding, but dropped it.

Comment: Thank you for a comprehensive summary--all good reasons for not translating my global specials to local specials. Will investigate other ways to reduce dependence on globals (in addition to passing local versions as arguments).