# Using a Closure instead of a Global Variable

Tags: closures, global-variables, common-lisp

This question is a continuation of the comments at [Using Local Special Variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56725814/using-local-special-variables), regarding how best to avoid global variables. As I understand it, global variables are problematic mainly because they have the potential to interfere with referential transparency. Transparency is violated if an expression changes a global value using information outside its calling context (eg, a previous value of the global variable itself, or any other external values). In these cases evaluating the expression may have different results at different times, either in the value(s) returned or in side effects. (However, it seems not all global updates are problematic, since some updates may not depend on any external information--eg, resetting a global counter to 0). The normal global approach for a deeply embedded counter might look like:

```
* (defparameter *x* 0)
*X*
* (defun foo ()
    (incf *x*))
FOO
* (defun bar ()
    (foo))
BAR
* (bar)
1
* *x*
1
```

This would seem to violate referential transparency because `(incf *x*)` depends on the external (global) value of `*x*` to do its work. The following is an attempt to maintain both functionality and referential transparency by eliminating the global variable, but I'm not convinced that it really does:

```
* (let ((x 0))
    (defun inc-x () (incf x))
    (defun reset-x () (setf x 0))
    (defun get-x () x))
GET-X
* (defun bar ()
    (inc-x))
BAR
* (defun foo ()
    (bar))
FOO
* (get-x)
0
* (foo)
1
* (get-x)
1
```

The global variable is now gone, but it still seems like the expression `(inc-x)` has a (latent) side effect, and it will return different (but unused) values each time it is called. Does this confirm that using a closure on the variable in question does not solve the transparency problem?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> global variables are problematic mainly because they have the potential to interfere with referential transparency

If one wants to create a global configuration value, a global variable in Common Lisp is just fine.

Often it's desirable to package a bunch of configuration state and then it may be better to put that into an object.

There is no general requirement for procedures to be *referential transparent*.

It's useful to guide software design by software engineering principles, but often easy debugging and maintenance is more important than strict principles.

```
(let ((x 0))
  (defun inc-x () (incf x))
  (defun reset-x () (setf x 0))
  (defun get-x () x))
```

Practically above means that it

- is difficult to inspect
- has problematic effects of reloading the code
- prohibits the file compiler to recognize the top-level nature of the functions
- creates a whole API for just managing a single variable

Comment: Glad to hear what looks like common sense re global variables. Guess you just need a balanced approach to using them, rather than blanket avoidance.

Comment: The suggestion to put his variables into a single construction (using CLOS) is a great solution if you have a lot of variables with structure, whereas I recommended a solution for having less  structured global information in an alist. Fit it to what you need.

Answer (score 5):

Referential transparency means that if you bind some variable `x` to an expression `e`, you can replace all occurrences of `x` by `e` without changing the outcome. For example:

```
(let ((e (* pi 2)))
  (list (cos e) (sin e)))
```

The above could be written:

```
(list (cos (* pi 2))
      (sin (* pi 2)))
```

The resulting value is equivalent to the first one for some useful definition of equivalence (here `equalp`, but you could choose another one). Contrast this with:

```
(let ((e (random))
  (list e e))
```

Here above, each call to `random` gives a different result (statistically), and thus the behaviour is different if you reuse the same result multiple times or generate a new after each call.

Special variables are like additional arguments to functions, they can influence the outcome of a result simply by being bound to different values. Consider `*default-pathname-defaults*`, which is used to build pathnames.

In fact, for a given binding of that variable, each call to `(merge-pathnames "foo")` returns the same result. The result changes only if you use the same expression in different dynamical context, which is no different than calling a function with different arguments.

The main difficulty is that the special variable is hidden, i.e. you might not know that it influences some expressions, and that's why you need them documented and limited in number.

What breaks referential transparency is the presence of side-effects, whether you are using lexical or special variables. In both cases, a place is modified as part of the execution of the function, which means that you need to consider *when* and *how often* you call it.

You could have better suggestions if you explained a bit more how your code is organized. You said that you have many special variables due to *prototyping* but in the refactoring you want to do it seems as-if you want to keep to prototypal code mostly untouched. Maybe there is a way to pack things in a nice modular way but we can't help without knowing more about why you need many special variables, etc.

Comment: Is there a way you could relate your comments more directly to my comments & question above? For example, which statements are muddled/mistaken? What you've mentioned seems generally consistent with my understanding (however cursory).

Answer (score 1):

That code isn't referentially transparent. It is an improvement from `special` variables though.

The code you put would be a functional [nonce](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cryptographic_nonce) if you dropped the `reset-x`.

My answer to [your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56725814/using-local-special-variables) had general guidelines about `special` variables. For your specific case, perhaps they are worth it? I could see the case for using special variables as a nonce, for example, where it is probably silly to pass them around.

Common Lisp has so many facilities for dealing with global information, so there is rarely a need for having lots of global variables. You could define an `*env*` alist to store your values in, or put them in a hash table, or put them into symbol plists, or package them in a closure to pass around, or do something else, or use CLOS.

Comment: But it looks to me like the CL global "facilities" you mention all involve creating another (heterogeneous) global variable. Even if you do this, don't you still have an issue with referential transparency, since each (now more deeply buried) update is yet another side-effect involving the new global variable? Is referential transparency more of an ideal than a practicality?

Comment: You would indeed still have the issue, though more abstraction from burying that implementation detail is probably better.

I mentioned the nonce because it is a great example of that abstraction in action: while not transparent, it is functional and abstracted, so it is almost as good.

Comment: @davypough if your problem is too many global variables, then using a higher level construct to package them, CLOS or otherwise, is the most straightforward step! Few people think you should get rid of *all* global variables, but less is better. Too many functional arguments is solved in the same way, consider an `environment` variable.

Answer (score 1):

Where is the side effect of the second example ? The `x` inside the `let` isn't accessible from the outside.

Here's another closure example, with top-level functions, and a counter explicitly inside it.

```
(defun repeater (n)
  (let ((counter -1))
     (lambda ()
       (if (< counter n)
         (incf counter)
         (setf counter 0)))))

(defparameter *my-repeater* (repeater 3))
;; *MY-REPEATER*
(funcall *my-repeater*)
0
(funcall *my-repeater*)
1
```

https://lispcookbook.github.io/cl-cookbook/functions.html#closures

Comment: Yes, the x inside the let isn't accessible from the outside, but a place is still being modified, isn't it? As coredump puts it, this side-effect breaks referential transparency. Your closure example does seem like an improvement on mine, as it involves only an anonymous, rather than top-level, function per Rainer Joswig's comment.