# Using a Local Special Variable Passed as a Final Argument

Tags: dynamic, global-variables, common-lisp

I hope this isn't beating a dead horse, but I'd like an opinion about another possible strategy for writing referentially transparent code. (The previous discussion about referential transparency is at [Using a Closure instead of a Global Variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56744420/using-a-closure-instead-of-a-global-variable/56747134?noredirect=1#comment100078745_56747134)). Again, the objective is to eliminate most global variables, but retain their convenience, without injecting bug-prone references or potentially non-functional behavior (ie, referential opaqueness, side-effects, and non-repeatable evaluations) into the code.

The proposal is to use local special variables to establish initial bindings, which can then be passed dynamically to the subsequent nested functions that eventually use them. The intended advantage, like globals, is that the local special variables do not need to be passed as arguments through all the intermediate functions (whose functionality has nothing to do with the local special variables). However to maintain referential transparency, they would be passed as arguments to the final consumer functions.

What I'm wondering about is whether floating a lot of dynamic variables around is prone to programming bugs. It doesn't seem particularly error prone to me, since any local rebinding of a previously bound variable should not affect the original binding, once it is released:

```
(defun main ()
  (let ((x 0))
    (declare (special x))
    (fum)))

(defun fum ()
  (let ((x 1))  ;inadvertant? use of x
    (setf x 2))
  (foo))

(defun foo ()
  (declare (special x))
  (bar x))

(defun bar (arg)  ;final consumer of x
  arg)

(main) => 0
```

Are there problems with this stragegy?

Comment: You go and revert years of Common Lisp development (special variables turn your brain into pudding), and then you chicken out and define a function that takes an argument? Why would you do that? Wasn't your goal to avoid passing arguments? **Seriously now** - *Are there problems with this stragegy?* - yes, a lot, debugging ie is a nightmare.

Comment: TL;DR; **yes**.

Comment: I was trying to point out that local special variables and referential transparency are not necessarily incompatible. If your nested functions are referentially transparent, you can *reliably* test them bottom up, one at a time. No complex debugging, just good simple tests for each.

Comment: Only because your code does not modify global variable, doesn't mean it's referentially transparent. In short it means that function operates only on its own arguments. What you do is the opposite. Please, do not start learning Lisp by reading here and there parts of *On Lisp*. Start with ie *Common Lisp: Introduction to symbolic computation*. *On Lisp* is not in any way a tutorial.

Comment: @davypough you should see the section in *Let Over Lambda* by Doug Hoyte, the [pandoric macros in chapter 6](https://letoverlambda.com/index.cl/guest/chap6.html#sec_7) do what you want. I edited my answer with an example.

Comment: @davypough Note that `fum` is not a use of the special binding `x`; it uses a separate, lexical, binding. That is, if you move `(foo)` into `fum`'s `let` then `main` will still return `0`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Now your functions are referencing a variable that is not guaranteed to be defined. Trying to execute `(foo)` at the repl will throw an unbound variable error. Not only is there referential opacity, but now **referential context error throwing**!

What you have here are globally bound routines, which can only be executed in the local context where `(declare (special x))` has been hinted. You may as well put those functions in a `labels` so they don't get accidentally used, though at that point you are choosing between closing the variables in functions, or closing the functions in a function:

```lisp
(defun main ()
  (labels ((fum ()
             (let ((x 1));Inadvertent use of x? 
               (setf x 2))
             (foo))
           (foo ()
             (declare (special x))
             (bar x))
           (bar (arg) arg)) ;Final consumer of x.
    (let ((x 0))
      (declare (special x))
      (fum))))
```

Wow, that is some ugly code!

After a convolution we can make `x` lexical! Now we can achieve the holy grail, referential transparency!

*Convolute*

```lisp
(defun main ()
  (let ((x 0))
    (labels ((fum ()
               (let ((x 1))
                 (setf x 2))
               (foo))
             (foo () (bar x))
             (bar (arg) arg));Final consumer of x.
      (fum))))
```

This code is much nicer, and lispy. It is essentially [your code to the other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56744420/using-a-closure-instead-of-a-global-variable), but the functions bindings are localized. This is at least better than using explosive global naming. The inner let does nothing, same as before. Though now it is less convoluted.

```lisp
CL-USER> (main) ;=> 0
```

Your test case is the same `(main) ;=> 0` in both. The principle is to just encapsulate your variables lexially instead of with dynamic `special` declarations. Now we can reduce the code even more by just passing things functionally in a single environment variable, [as suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56744420/using-a-closure-instead-of-a-global-variable).

```lisp
(defun convoluted-zero ()
  (labels ((fum (x)
             (let ((x 1))
               (setf x 2))
             (foo x))
           (foo (x) (bar x))
           (bar (arg) arg)).
    (fum 0)))
```

```lisp
CL-USER> (let ((x (convoluted-zero)))
             (list x (convoluted-zero)))
;=> 0
```

□ **QED** your code with the special variables violates abstraction.

If you really want to go down the rabbit hole, you can read the [section of chapter 6 of Doug Hoyte's *Let Over Lambda* on pandoric macros](https://letoverlambda.com/index.cl/guest/chap6.html#sec_7), where you can do something like this:

```
(use-package :let-over-lambda)
(let ((c 0))
  (setf (symbol-function 'ludicrous+)
        (plambda () (c) (incf c)))
  (setf (symbol-function 'ludicrous-)
        (plambda () (c)(decf c))))
```

You can then use `pandoric-get` to get c without incrementing it or defining any accessor function in that context, which is absolute bonkers. With lisp packages you can get away with a package-local "global" variable. I could see an application for this in elisp, for example, which has no packages built in.

Comment: Great explanation--thanks for wading thru this with me! I guess my take-away is to look first at bundling individual globals into some kind of global container object. Technically it does not provide referential transparency, but it at least offers a layer of protection from inadvertant modifications.

Comment: Yes, good plan. You could use an immutable global object to attain transparency, like in Clojure. @davypough

Comment: Looking forward to pandoric macros--thanks! It's over my head, but the abstractions of CL are fascinating.

Comment: @davypough the fact that they are over your head shows why, in my opinion, they are a bad idea: they are far more complex than just using a package-local variable (i.e. global).

Comment: Granted, but I'd be willing to bet they are a perfect fit for some obscure programming situation. Besides, exploring CL is fun ;)  You've really helped there!