# Defining and acessing variables in a local environment

Tags: scope, macros, common-lisp

After quite a while of studying CL and practising as a hobby in different small projects, I still have some blank areas on my personal CL map. Recently, I had a number of functions using all the same `let` construct and I thought of writing a macro which makes the code more concise:

```
(defmacro with-context (&body body)
   `(let ((context (make-array 4 :element-type 'fixnum
                                 :initial-contents '(0 1 2 3))))
     ,@body))
```

So that I can later define functions like (just as a minimal example):

```
(defun test-a ()
  (with-context
    (setf (aref context 3)
          (+ (aref context 0) (aref context 1)))
    context))
```

Now I was wondering if I could shorten the `(aref context n)` expressions with a macro/function like `(context n)`.

```
(defun context (n)
  (aref context n))
```

But the variable `context` is unknown at compile time, of course. I just don't know if I have a case of basic misunderstanding here or how I could tell lisp what I actually want. So, my question is basically if it is possible and if it is a good idea.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What's wrong with a local function?

```
(defmacro with-context (&body body)
  `(let ((context (make-array 4 :initial-contents '(0 1 2 3))))
     (flet ((context (n)
              (aref context n)))
       ,@body)))
```

Setting, too:

```
(defmacro with-context (&body body)
  `(let ((context (make-array 4 :initial-contents '(0 1 2 3))))
     (flet ((context (n)
              (aref context n))
            ((setf context) (new n)
              (setf (aref context n) new)))
       ,@body)))
```

Comment: This wouldn't be a place you could `setf`, no?

Comment: @Svante: added now

Comment: Thanks for clarification. Just for my understanding: If if have a `main` function using `with-context`and other function defined outside of `main` which want to use `context` I end up in a situation similar to the one discussed in another [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56762865/using-a-local-special-variable-passed-as-a-final-argument), recently and should consider another strategy, I guess.

Comment: @RainerJoswig I will try ;-)

Answer (score 3):

You could put a `macrolet` into your macro expansion:

```
(defmacro with-context (&body body)
  (with-gensyms (i)
    `(let ((context (make-array 4 …)))
       (macrolet ((context (,i)
                    `(aref context ,,i)))
         ,@body))))
```

Some personal notes:

I dislike anaphoric macros, so I'd generally let the user define the name for the context.  That would feel strange with the `context` macrolet though.  I'd then maybe come to the conclusion that all I want is a `make-standard-context` function and keep using `let`.  I think this is in line with the general guideline “be conventional”.

Comment: I understand your point and will consider another solution. Nevertheless, I think there is a `,` missing before `\`(aref context ,i)`